# can not access external css and js at .vm using spring framework and run it on tomcat server?

Tags: css, spring, tomcat, velocity

I have a web application with spring framework and velocity template language.
My folder structure is below:

**webapp**

- style
- mystyle.css

**WEB-INF**

- layouts

  - layout.vm /
- view
  -template
  -mytemplate.vm

I am calling the mytemplate.vm from MyController. When I deploy the application it will render cross ponding .vm file but can not load the external css when i start the tomcat server. I use the following code

```
<link href="style/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

in the layout.vm file...

How could I use external CSS & JS in '.vm' file?

Answer (score 0):

Your directory structure to run your project in Tomcat must be like:

$Tomcat_Home/webapps/YourProject
add your css, js, html, jsp files here

Your libraries in $Tomcat_Home/webapps/YourProject/WEB-INF/lib and your servlet code in $Tomcat_Home/webapps/YourProject/WEB-INF/classes